# No signature of method: static org.springframework.security.oauth.User.withTransaction()

Tags: spring, maven, groovy, spring-security, grails-orm

i have a problem is shown below;

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
    static org.springframework.security.oauth.User.withTransaction() is applicable for argument types:
    (org.springframework.security.oauth.services.UserService$_saveUser_closure1) values:
    [org.springframework.security.oauth.services.UserService$_saveUser_closure1@2ed1e8 at 
    groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1357)
```

UserService:

```
class UserService {

  public boolean saveUser(){
    boolean retVal=false;
    User.withTransaction{status ->
      def sUser = new User()
      sUser.setUsername("muhammed")
      sUser.save()
      retVal= true
    }
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

User.groovy:

```
@Entity
class User {
  String id;
  String username;
  String password;//social agent id

  static constraints = {
    username(nullable:true)
    password(nullable:true)
  }
  static mapping  = {
    id generator: 'uuid'
  }
}
```

what is the problem i cant find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you imported the wrong User class in your service. Most likely you have something like

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth.User
```

on top of your UserService.groovy file, whereas you need to import your domain class.

Comment: i changed to hibernate it works now,groovy is really sick me:)